# String length Error

Tags: c, string, loops

I am reading the string from the stdin using fgets function and then trying to print the length of the string, But I am always getting the length of the string as 1 always for the first time 
Here is my code

```
#incldue<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
   printf("\n Enter the no of test cases");
   scanf("%d",&t);
   int i,j;
   for(i=0;i<t;++i)
   {
     char song[500],val[28];
     int k=0,x=0;
     fgets(song,500,stdin);
     int len=strlen(song);
     printf("\nlen=%d",len);
   }
  return 0;
}
```

I am always getting 1 as the length for the first test case :/
Please suggest where i am going wrong

Comment: Remember pressing the enter key for the `scanf`? This character(`\n`) is consumed by the `fgets` in the first iteration

Comment: OT: `strlen()` returns `size_t` not `int`.

Comment: where is the 't' variable defined?\

Comment: variable 'j', 'k', 'x', and val[] are not used , they cause the compiler to raise  warnings.  suggest eliminate those variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not clearing the input buffer. After giving the input value to first `scanf` newline will be there. So `fgets` will not get the input from the user.
Newline will be placed in that buffer in a first(`song[0]`) position. So this is the reason strlen returns as value `1`.

Make this line before the `fgets`.

```
int c;
if ( i == 0 )
    while((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF );
fgets(song,500,stdin);
```

---

Or else place this line after getting the input from the `scanf`.

```
scanf("%d",&t);
while((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF );
```

Answer (score 3):

Include `\n` in `scanf` input string (and in C declare variables at the beginning of the *block* `{ }`).

Also notice the len will include the `\n` char.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    int t, i;
    printf("Enter the no of test cases: ");
    scanf("%d\n",&t);
    for(i=0;i<t;++i) {
        char song[500];
        int len;

        fgets(song,500,stdin);
        len=strlen(song);
        printf("len=%d\n",len);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**update**

If you need to handle weird input just use `fgets` (`\n` removed from *len*).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    char song[500];
    int t, i, len;  
    printf("Enter the no of test cases: ");
    fgets(song,500,stdin);
    t = atoi(song);
    for(i=0;i<t;++i) {
        fgets(song,500,stdin);
        if ((len=strlen(song)) > 0) {
            song[--len] = '\0';
            printf("len=%d\n",len);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I must say this looks so simple and elegant solution

Comment: This *can* lead to problems as a whitespace character in the format string instructs `scanf` to skip any number of whitespace characters including none **until the first non-whitespace character**. So , when you think that the execution of the program has reached the `fgets` in the first iteration, you're wrong. The execution is still in the `scanf`.

Comment: Thank you @CoolGuy for pointing out the problem, may you provide an example of input that would cause problems?

Comment: @Alex , Actually, I was saying that adding, say, a `printf` just before the `fgets` causes a problem as the text in the `printf` does not appear when one enters the number of test cases for the first `scanf`. It appears only when you press enter. But note that this happens only in the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

When using `scanf` (or its relatives), it is important to check the return of the function. `scanf` returns the number of input values correctly matched and assigned. If there are inappropriate characters or insufficient characters, `scanf` will experience a **matching** or **input** failure. A quick `if` statement will suffice:

```
    if (!scanf ("%d", &t)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid type or number for test cases.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

As also noted, `fgets` will read and include in `song` the trailing `newline` character. Generally, you will want to remove the trailing `newline` to prevent having stray newlines scattered through various strings within your code. (not to mention looking at a `length=5` for `data` is a bit strange) A simple method for removing the `newline` after your call to `fgets` is:

```
            len = strlen (song);
            while (len && song[len-1] == '\n')  /* strip newline */
                song[--len] = 0;
```

Putting together the test of `scanf` return, emptying the input buffer, and stripping the `newline` after `fgets`, your code would look similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    int c = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int t = 0;

    printf ("\n Enter the no of test cases: ");
    if (!scanf ("%d", &t)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid type or number for test cases.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

    for (i = 0; i < t; ++i) {

        char song[500] = { 0 };
        size_t len = 0;

        if (printf ("\n    case [%d] : ", i) && fgets (song, 500, stdin))
        {
            len = strlen (song);
            while (len && song[len-1] == '\n')  /* strip newline */
                song[--len] = 0;
        }
        printf ("         len : %zu\n", len);
    }

    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_rd_int

 Enter the no of test cases: 2

    case [0] : this is case one - 28 chars.
         len : 28

    case [1] : this is case two -- 29 chars.
         len : 29
```